# How to fix this login failed for user?

Tags: sql, sql-server

[User,privilege and role](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VA4hX.png)
This is my first time using MS studio I am learning by myself

I tried going to the login properties and tweaking the properties nothing happen. My teacher didn't teach how to use this btw. I follow the instructions, but I'm stuck here.

This is what I am aiming for result
[New user login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khDHD.png)

Comment: Guess what? MySQL and SQLIte are a totally different products to SQL Server - do yourself a favour and correct your tags so the right experts look at your post.

Comment: Details of login failures are not returned to the client application for security reasons but you can see the specific cause in the SQL Server error log. The log can be viewed in SQL Server object explorer under Management-->SQL Server logs. Double-click on the current one.

Comment: Thanks dan guzman, this is what appeared.
Login failed for user 'User'. Reason: An attempt to login using SQL authentication failed. Server is configured for Integrated authentication only. [CLIENT: <local machine>]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is change the [server authentication mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/change-server-authentication-mode?view=sql-server-ver16) to "**SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode**". Currently your server is only set to "Windows Authentication mode" which does not allow logins from SQL Server "Login" accounts.

To do so, you'll need to login to your server as an account that has access (either an authenticated Windows account or the SA account) and then follow these instructions:

> **Change authentication mode with SSMS**
>
> 1. In SQL Server Management Studio Object Explorer, right-click the server, and then click Properties.
> 2. On the Security page, under Server authentication, select the new server authentication mode, and then click OK.
> 3. In the SQL Server Management Studio dialog box, click OK to acknowledge the requirement to restart SQL Server.
> 4. In Object Explorer, right-click your server, and then click Restart. If SQL Server Agent is running, it must also be restarted.